# Lucene/Solr for approximate (company) name matching

Tags: java, solr, lucene, matching, approximate

I have a question regarding Lucene/Solr.

I am trying to solve a general (company) name matching problem.

Let me present one oversimplified example:

We have two (possibly large) lists of names viz., list_A and list_B. 
We want to find the intersection of the two lists, but the names in the two lists may not always exactly match. For each distinct name in list_A, we will want to report one or more best matches from list_B.

I have heard that Lucene/Solr can solve this problem. Can you tell me if this is true? If it is, please point me to some minimal working example(s).

Thanks and regards,
Dibyendu

Comment: Arun/femtoRgon, I have already considered the edit distance based approaches. I want to try Lucene/Solr in the hope of improving the results. From your experience, please do let me know the chances of improvement.

Comment: You are barking up the wrong tree.  If you aren't happy with an edit distance comparison, try a different algorithm.  Think about what you want to accomplish with the comparison.  I don't know what you need, really, but since you are matching names, I suspect something like Metaphone (which is based on phonetic similarity, rather than edit distance) might be a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this with Lucene, yes, but if you just need to solve this one problem, creating a Lucene index would be a bit of a roundabout way to do it.

I'dd be more inclined to take a simpler approach.  You could just find a library for fuzzy comparison between strings, and iterate through your lists and return only those under a certain threshold of similarity as matches.

[org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) comes to mind, something like:

```
for (String a : alist) {
    for (String b : blist) {
        int dist = StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(a,b)
        if (dist < threshold) {
            //b is a good enough match for a, do something with it!
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on your intent, other algorithms might be more appropriate ([Soundex](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Soundex.html) or [Metaphone](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Metaphone.html), for instance)

Comment: Thanks a lot, femtoRgon. Please see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

SOLR can solve your problem. Index the list_B in SOLR. Now do a search for every item in list_A in SOLR, you will get one or more likely match from the list_B. 
You need to configure analyzers and filters for the field according to your data set and what kind of similar result you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Arun. Please see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do something similar, and I would like to point out to the other commenters that their proposed solutions (like Levenshtein Distance or Soundex) may not be appropriate, if the problem is matching of accurate names, as opposed to mis-spelled names.

For example: I doubt either one is much use for matching

```
John S W Edward
```

with

```
J Samuel Woodhouse Edward
```

I suppose it is possible, but this is a different class of problem than what they were intended to accomplish.